# jquery add background image with dynamic url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi and hope you can help. My JavaScript isn't that hot and I have tried searching but had no luck with find the correct method.

I am trying to add css background-image to a div (.jumbotron) but dynamically change the url depending on the screen size. The image will be picked up from https://unsplash.it where the url can be coded to the dimensions required i.e. 
    https://unsplash.it/200/300

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function setBackground () {
    $('jumbotron').css('background-image', 'url(https://unsplash.it/' + $(window).height(); + '/' + $(window).width();')');
}
</script>
```

I hope this make sense and thanks in advance

Comment: What is jumbotron? Is it an id/class? It probably needs a selector tag (ex. `.jumbotron` or `#jumbotron`). Also, you have an extra `>` on the closing script tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `jumbotron` is an id or class, make sure you give it a selector tag.

You can do something like this to achieve what you are wanting: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xppandLo/5/)

```
function setBackground() {
    var height = $(window).height();
    var width = $(window).width();
    $('.jumbotron').css('background-image', 'url(https://unsplash.it/' + width + '/' + height + ')');
}
```

**Notes on your original:**
`jumbotron` needed a selector tag (class/id)
`$(window).width();` was missing a `+` after it.
For the Upslash link, the width needs to be before height to work properly.

**One more note:**
Do you want this function to run on load? If so, be sure to call that function since its not set to run instantly.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the semi colon in the string.

```
function setBackground () {
    $('jumbotron').css('background-image', 'url(https://unsplash.it/' + $(window).height() + '/' + $(window).width()')');
}
```

Having a semicolon in the middle of the string will force it to stop before the string is completed.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function setBackground () {
$('jumbotron').css('background-image', 'url(https://unsplash.it/' + $(window).height(); + '/' + $(window).width(); + ')');
}
</script>>
```

you have missed the '+' sign after width.